# Report Builder: How to sort parameter list

Tags: ssas, report-builder2.0

The situation: I am generating reports using Report Builder 2.0 and a Report Model that I have created.

The question: How does one sort a parameter list alphabetically? Simple question, but I can't find the answer for the life of me. Kudos to whoever can provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer to my question does not exist because it is not possible. There is an [open issue at connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/305893/sorting-parameters-for-reports-developed-with-report-builder) for this missing feature. Please upvote it on Microsoft's site so that they will fix it in the upcoming version of Report Builder. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Depends how your defining the list, but most commonly by adding an order by statement to the sql that defines the parameter list.

Comment: As the question states, I am tied to a Report Model, and therefore do not have direct database access.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found a work around.
My problem was that I was trying to do this when using a report model as the data source. It seems like the report builder sorted by the left hand most field in the query but when using the model this always seems to be a model generated reference field rather than the actual data held in the field you want.

To have better control of the order in which the entries appeared i did the following.

I created a new field based on the field I wanted to use.
Then put this new field rather than the original field from the data model as the left most field in the query.

Comment: I needed a parameter showing a list of Fiscal Years in descending order.  I added a column to my dataset with its value = 100000-FY.  I made this the first column and it now correctly orders the Fiscal Years from my model.  Its a hack, but it works.